# Implement model portion of the MVC

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I have a simple game made, still working on some of the additional portions of the game. I am not sure how/where to store my game data (scores, settings, etc)

I've been using a singleton with all of the data that I'll use in the program synthesized for ease of access, but I don't know if this is a good method? It seems to me it would make settings and such quite easy, because I can just share the singleton among the menu view and the game view, without having to copy the data.. Is there another way? Every book I've read so far seems to skip over the model and just combine it with the controller portion of the MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons while appealing for their simplicity generally make the code base less flexible to changes.  They also do not encourage a clear separation of functionality in the model.

An alternative is to use core data for the model.  You would have a managed object for game,scores, settings etc and pass around references to the objects.  With Core Data you get persistence for free along with fast/efficient mechanisms for sorting and presenting data.